# Algorithm to identify variable that best explains other variables

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, binary-data

I have a set of almost 100 binary variables. Some variables are highly correlated, others are not. They all have a similar meaning (signals of related trading strategies) but differ due to slightly different ways to compute them.

I want to find the variable that has most in common with the other variables (i.e., explains most of what they explain).

Do you have a suggestion for an appropriate algorithm to find that variable and to also measure (in a certain way) the portion explained by that variable?

Comment: I think mutual information or conditional mutual information (CMI) can be the right tools for you

Comment: What about looking at the ratio of the total variance of the data matrix (trace of covariance matrix) to the total variance of the residual matrix of the regression of all variables onto each single predictor? That would appear to be the proportion of variance explained in the data matrix by the regression onto each variable.

Comment: @Ryan Volpi: Thanks for this idea. To get this right: If I have 100 variables, I would compute your measure for the first variable X_1 by regressing X_1 = b_1 + b_2*X_2 + ... +  b_100*X_100 and computing the variance of the residuals. This one I scale with the trace of the covariance matrix of the 100 variables. Right?

Comment: Close, but actually the opposite form of that regression. What you describe will give you a measure proportional to the variance inflation factor which describes the degree of multicollinearity associated with each variable. You can see how it will diverge from what you want when you consider two perfectly proportionate variables, say X_1 and X_2. Even if they are not correlated with any other variable, the regression of X1 onto all other variables will explain all of the variance. And yet, X1 doesn't necessarily explain the most variance in the full set of predictors.

Comment: My suggestion, to measure the explained variance of, say, X1, is to regress all variables onto X1. So X2~X1,  X3~X1, etc. You can then create a covariance matrix of the residuals of the regressions for X1 and compute the trace of that. Then: 1- (trace of residual matrix)/(trace of original data matrix)  could be an estimate of variance explained by X1.

Comment: variable clustering,  correspondence analysis